# Dual-Grid Graph Paper With Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra

Is there a slick way to generate the dual-grid graphs such as you can see on pages 7, 9, and 10 of [this article](http://online.redwoods.cc.ca.us/instruct/darnold/linalg/CoordinateSystems/coordinatesystems-p.pdf), or [this one](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/4/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=560&bodyId=846)?

I've searched, but found nothing. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**By definition,** a (real) "coordinate" is a map from a region into the Real numbers.  To show a coordinate, we usually fix specific values, such as $\ldots, -3, -2, \ldots, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and graph the inverse images (level sets) of these values.  We will want to distinguish different coordinates by varying the graphical representations of these level sets.

**We should encapsulate** these elements--coordinate functions, graphical attributes, and discrete sets of values--in some convenient data structure.  The simplest to use is a list.  For example, here are descriptions of a pair of Cartesian coordinates and a pair of Polar coordinates:

```
coordinates = {
   {#1 &, Gray, Range[-3, 3]},
   {#2 &, Gray, Range[-3, 3]},
   {Norm[{#1, #2}] &, Directive[Darker[Red], Dashed], Range[-3, 3]},
   {ArcTan[#1, #2] &, Directive[Darker[Red], Dashed], Range[-\[Pi] + \[Pi]/7, \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/7]}
   };
```

**Here's the "slick" part:** merely map `ContourPlot` over this list and wrap it all in `Show` to overlay the whole bunch.

```
Show[ContourPlot[#1[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Contours -> #3, 
    ContourStyle -> #2, ContourShading -> None] & @@@ coordinates]
```

[image: Cartesian and polar coordinates]

(The mashup along the negative $x$ axis is a *Mathematica* problem with contouring `ArcTan`; it's not the result of this particular method.)

In a similar way **we can reproduce the Arnold figures** *using the very calculations they are intended to illustrate*.  Here is (most) of one of them:

```
basis = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}; (* New basis *)
dual = Inverse[basis];     (* New coordinate functions *)
green = ConstantArray[Green, 8]~Join~{Black}~Join~ConstantArray[Green, 8];
coordinates = {
   {(dual.{#1, #2} // First) &, green, Range[-8, 8]},
   {(dual.{#1, #2} // Last) &, green, Range[-8, 8]},
   {#1 &, LightGray, Range[-5, 5]},
   {#2 &, LightGray, Range[-5, 5]}
   };
Show[ContourPlot[#1[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> #3, 
    ContourStyle -> #2, ContourShading -> None] & @@@ coordinates]
```

[image: Figure reproduction]

This is not limited to two coordinate systems: `coordinates` can be a list of any length, allowing display of any number of coordinate functions simultaneously.  And it is direct: you do not have to work out the inverse coordinate functions (which would be required with a solution based on `Plot` or `ParametricPlot`, for instance).

Comment: Excellent answer, as always!

Comment: This is an extremely helpful answer. Many thanks. My ability with Mathematica is very limited, and I couldn't have come up with this at all, but I can edit this to meet my needs.

Answer (score 8):

A possible starting point:

```
With[{θ = π/3}, 
 DeleteCases[
             ParametricPlot[{{x, y}, RotationTransform[-θ][Sqrt[2] {x, y}]},
                            {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
             _Polygon, ∞]]
```

[image: dual grid]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a start using just simple plotting functions.

```
With[{m = 5},
    Plot[
        {Table[i x + j, {j, -2 m, 2 m}, {i, {-1, 1}}], Sequence[-x, x]}, {x, -m, m}, 
        AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {-m, m}, PlotStyle -> {Green, {Thick, Black}}, 
        AxesStyle -> Thick, Ticks -> None, GridLines -> ({Range[-m, m], Range[-m, m]}), 
        GridLinesStyle -> Directive@LightGray
    ]
]
```

[image]

You can get fancier and gain more control using graphics primitives.

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. How could this be modified to incorporate a different basis for R^2, like {{3,1},{1,2}}?

Comment: @ZippyThePinhead I didn't read the article... just saw the figure. Do you want to orient the lines along some rotation θ instead? If so, then you'll have to use `RotationTransform` with primitives or as in J.M.'s answer.

Comment: No, I want to be able to pick two basis vectors for R^2 and show the coordinate system that results, superposed over R^2 with a different basis. The grid you generated above would correspond to the standard basis (background, grey) and the basis {{-sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2},{sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2}} (green).

Comment: @Zippy, then the version in my answer is the one you're looking for. You're familiar with rotation matrices, I gather?

Comment: Yes, and I'm going to work with the example code you provided. Everyone has been very helpful, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish things like this by defining your own functions to generate descriptions for `Graphics` here is a simple function that generates a grid over two arbitrary basis vectors:

```
 genGrid[v1_, v2_, l_: 10] := {
 Line /@ Table[v1 n1 + v2 n2, {n1, -l, l}, {n2, {-l, l}}],
 Line /@ Table[v1 n1 + v2 n2, {n2, -l, l}, {n1, {-l, l}}]
 }
```

You can then use it along with other graphics options to style your resulting figure:

```
 Graphics[{
 {Black, genGrid[{1, 0}, {0, 1}]},
 {Gray, genGrid[{1, 1}, {2, 1}, 14]}
 }, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image: Graph showing two different axes.]

To add things such as arrows and anotations you can use `Arrow` and `Text`.

Comment: For me that graphic is an optical illusion: it makes the main grid look decidedly crooked.